# Find the area of the surface obtained by rotating the curve about the x-axis?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Given this curve: $$y=\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{1}{2x}  1/2 \le x \le 1 $$

This is what I get for my (dy/dx)^2:

$$\frac{x^4+x^{-4}+2}{4}$$

I'm unsure about this. Can anyone confirm that I did it correctly?
I need the correct (dy/dx)^2 so I can use this formula later on:

$$\int2πy\sqrt{1+(\frac{dy}{dx})^2}  dx$$

Comment: Your $\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2$ should be $\frac{x^4+x^{-4}-2}{4}$.  Then you can check whether $1+\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2$ is a perfect square so you can simplify its square root.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Observe that

$$\left(x^4+x^{-4}+2\right)=\left(x^2+\frac1{x^2}\right)^2$$

Answer (score 0):

Differentiate $y=\frac{1}{6}x^3+\frac{1}{2x}$, then $y'=\frac{1}{2}x^2 - \frac{1}{2x^2}$. Thus
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x^4-2+x^{-4}}{4},
$$
not $\frac{x^4+2+x^{-4}}{4}$. Therefore,
$$
\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2}= \frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{1}{2x^2}.
$$